# post var problem with shortcode loop

Tags: query-posts, shortcode

I have a function to display the children of the page in the sidebar php file using wp_list_pages:

```
global $post; ?>
        <div id="subChildren">
        <?php if($post->post_parent)
        $children = wp_list_pages("sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); else
        $children = wp_list_pages("sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
        if ($children) { ?>
        
        <ul id="submenu">
        <?php echo $children; ?>
         
        </ul>
```

I have also created a shortcode that shows a custom post type using query posts:

```
function casestudy_shortcode()
    {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'type' => 'case_studies',
            'limit' => '1',
            'case' => '',
            'size' => 'small'
            ),$atts));
     
            //The Query
        query_posts('post_type='.$type.'&showposts='.$limit.'&p='.$case);

        //The Loop
       if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                   //return sb_post_image('100','100');
                //the_post_thumbnail('portfolio'); 
                return  "<div class='".$size."'><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".get_the_title()."</a>" . get_the_excerpt() ."</div>";;
      
        endwhile; else:
    endif;
     
        wp_reset_query();    
        
    }
    add_shortcode('casestudy', 'casestudy_shortcode');
```

The problem I have is that when the shortcode is in a page it makes the sub pages not show up. I assume it is overriding the $post variable.

I have tried using wp_query and get_posts for the shortcode but i get the same result.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you really shouldn't use `query_posts()` for anything other then the main query of the page. Instead you should use [wp_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) or [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) , also since you return a value before running wp_reset_query() then its never actually being reset.

so change your shortcode to this:

```
function casestudy_shortcode($atts){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'type' => 'case_studies',
            'limit' => '1',
            'case' => '',
            'size' => 'small'
            ),$atts));

    //save the real $post
    global $post; 
    $real = $post;

    //The Query
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'posts_per_page' => $limit);
    if ($case != ''){
        $args['p'] = $case;
    }

    $s_query = NEW WP_Query($args);


    //The Loop
    if ( $s_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $s_query->have_posts() ) : $s_query->the_post();
        //return sb_post_image('100','100');
        //the_post_thumbnail('portfolio'); 
        $return .= "<div class='".$size."'><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".get_the_title()."</a>" . get_the_excerpt() ."</div>";
    endwhile; else:
    endif;
     $post = $real;
        wp_reset_query();    
        return $return;

}
    add_shortcode('casestudy', 'casestudy_shortcode');
```

Comment: Perfect thanks worked like a charm :)
I did try using wp_query but it didn't work for me as you rightly pointed out my reset was in the wrong place.